# Import / read / load variables from matlab matfile in C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I've been searching for a while to see if anyone has done any work on reading Matlab mat files in CSharp, and it seems that there is nothing out there.

Has anybody seen any solutions?

I can't simply export my mat files to text and then read them into my C# code, because there are fairly complex structures.

I don't like to inter operate with Matlab and I don't want to use Python ([SciPy with loadmat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html)) either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option to try is the submission [CSMatIO](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16319) by [David Zier](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/29236) on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange). It's an API for .NET 2.0 that will allow you to read level 5 .mat files.

If you have to read newer .mat file formats, you can first load your .mat file into MATLAB and resave it as an older format using the [SAVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) function's *version* option.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a HD5 reader to get the data out of new .mat files, though you may need to put in some work.

Comment: I just tried David Zier's libraries, they work for me, although they are not easy to work with and need a lot of twist to get my complex structures out but they are so far the best available. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net) is able to read and write to/from Matlab mat files, version 6.

Answer (score 2):

Since CSMatIO doesn't seem to be supported, I'd like to share a link to a similar library for reading/writing MATLAB .mat files: [MatFileHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MatFileHandler/), which targets .NET Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add another alternative. The Accord.Math library (available via Nuget, or here: http://accord-framework.net/ provides a .mat file reader.