# How to open a .mat file (Matlab) with c# without Matlab installed?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import / read / load variables from matlab matfile it C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281348/import-read-load-variables-from-matlab-matfile-it-c)

I want to write a c# program that opens a .mat file (Matlab) without instantiating a COM Matlab Server. Is there a library to do so?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281348/import-read-load-variables-from-matlab-matfile-it-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MatLab File Format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf)

Comment: Fantastic... have you come across a .Net library for it?

Comment: -1 not a very helpful answer. Writing your own library for parsing this complex format would be a really ambitious project. Besides you do not want to reinvent the wheel..