# read .mat file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import / read / load variables from matlab matfile it C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281348/import-read-load-variables-from-matlab-matfile-it-c-sharp)

I am not a matlab expert, I am looking for some class library which shall read matlab file (.mat) developed in .net

Please suggest any opensource api

Answer (score 1):

The [CSMatIO](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16319) submission on the file exchange exposes a .Net API for accessing .mat files. AFAIK .mat files are just [HDF5](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) files, so you may be able to get an HDF5 reader to read them as well.

Comment: Only version 7.3 of MAT-files uses HDF5 format.