# extracting an output matrix from matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, iris-recognition

I am working on a small iris recognition system using matlab, my matlab code after several steps and algorithms gives me a 9600 bit matrix as an output, and I was wondering how can I take this matrix to process it using a Windows Forms application using C#?

Comment: what about tabulated text?

Answer (score 1):

There are some standard formats that you can work with them both in MATLAB and C#.

For example, you can use `csvwrite` function in MATLAB to save it as a comma-separated value file. The in C# there are standard ways to read a csv file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array) it is discussed how to read a CSV file in C#.

Another option is to save in a .txt file and read it in C#. HDF5 files are another type that are supported with some libraries in both (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/hdf5-files.html)). You can even save your file as a regular .mat file and load it in C# using a specific API (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281348/import-read-load-variables-from-matlab-matfile-in-c-sharp))